# Junit Spring avoid to load twice application context datasource

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have this configuration classes:

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = { 
                "mypackage.controller",
                "mypackage.service",
                "mypackage.repository" 
        }
)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:configuration.properties")
@Import({
    H2Configuration.class
})
public class TestConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
public class H2Configuration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("h2/create.sql")
                .addScript("h2/insert.sql")
                .build();
        db.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
        return db;
    }

}
```

And I have this two class tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { TestConfiguration.class })
public class FirstRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    MyFirstRepositoryImpl repository;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testNullRecords() {
        repository.foo(null, null);
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { TestConfiguration.class })
public class SecondRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    MySecondRepositoryImpl repository;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testSomethingNullRecords() {
        repository.something(null, null);
    }
}
```

If I run junit test once for each class, all goes well.

In clean install phase tests fails because the application context is initialized twice.

For example it try to create the h2 tables twice and do the insert.sql script twice.

What I have to do for initialize the h2 database and so application context only once?

Thanks

Comment: **NB** `db.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);` is wasteful (as it get a single connection from the datasource and sets auto commit to false on that connection) and leaks a connection (the connection returned is potentially from a pool backed source). You should remove that line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could start looking at the Spring documentation about [Integration Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing).

It can also be a good practice to use transactional tests for integration tests (`@Transactional`), which rollback at the end of each test : see [Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

To avoid the cost of recreating the `ApplicationContext` for each test class, the cache may be used as explained here : [Context Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching).

For integration testing with **Embedded Database**, you can also find documentation : [Testing Data Access Logic with an Embedded Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-embedded-database-dao-testing).
A note from the previous link, matching your use case :

> However, if you wish to create an embedded database that is shared
>   within a test suite, consider using the Spring TestContext Framework
>   and configuring the embedded database as a bean in the Spring
>   ApplicationContext as described in Creating an Embedded Database by
>   Using Spring XML and Creating an Embedded Database Programmatically.

I hope you will find some useful references.

Comment: So you could for example call `EmbeddedDatabase.shutdown()` in `@After` or `@AfterClass` like in the example from the Spring doc (_Testing Data Access Logic with an Embedded Database_).

Comment: I am using in memory db for the unit test, so it's not necessary to rollback.

Comment: In fact the objective of rollbacks after tests is to provide a clear isolation between integration tests. It also avoids having to clean after the test.

Answer (score 3):

Another good tip I found from **Spring Boot** documentation from [Embedded Database Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support) :

They say :

> If you are using this feature in your tests, you may notice that the
>   same database is reused by your whole test suite regardless of the
>   number of application contexts that you use. If you want to make sure
>   that each context has a separate embedded database, you should set
>   spring.datasource.generate-unique-name to true.

So to make each `EmbeddedDatabase` unique, you may try to create them with :

```
EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                      .generateUniqueName(true)
                      ...
                      .build();
```

Comment: That is an interesting option and would also solve this problem - thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2):

In unit testing you must garantee that every test is repeatible hance context independent. Due to this is not good idea to load the context only once. Is better to reset after the execution. For this you can use **@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) in your test classes**

So you will force your context to restart when the next junit class is launched

Comment: Application context is independent but the in memory db is the same

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your Spring context this will totally kill performance of unit tests. In our case it takes 30s to completely initialize the Spring context, which makes DirtiesContext totally unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason that this is failing is that the database (H2) is resident in memory when you run the tests as part of clean/install. The create/insert scripts have already executed after the first test is run. Any subsequent test execution after this point will result in a re-execution of the same script(s) and the error will occur.

Update your create script with a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table name>;`. This will ensure that the table is dropped then recreated.

**NOTE**: I'm not sure why you've specified `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` explicitly. I think, without that, the runner `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` will cache contexts that have not been changed. I don't know specifically if that is the case here though.

Comment: I have tried to remove AnnotationConfigContextLoader, but without the drop tables the clean install fail. So the drop before the create are necessary. I removed anyway  AnnotationConfigContextLoader, it's unnecessary as you can say (I think).

Comment: Yes the bean is, in this case, being recreated which results in the scripts being executed. The database is persistent in memory across tests in the same run which is why the drop statements are necessary.